# NGINX: add_header for GET not working

Tags: nginx

The following (simplified) NGINX config results in OPTIONS calls correctly getting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header headers in return, but GET not:

```
location / {
    if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '$http_origin' always;
        return 204;
    }
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '$http_origin' always;
    try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
}

location @proxy_to_app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app_server;
}
```

I've tried every combination in the `location` block, but nothing works, the only solution I could think of that works is moving the this line into the `location @proxy_to_app` section:

```
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '$http_origin' always;
```

It's like that `proxy_to_app` block is removing the added headers again.

Comment: Put `add_header` to `location @proxy_to_app`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alexey Ten stated, I moved `add_header` into location `@proxy_to_app`